# Why the logo didn't appear in website?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

```
<div class="AuthorizeNetSeal"> <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">var ANS_customer_id="c7a332ea-b9ec-47dd-b5e2-5fabae719bfb";</script> <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//verify.authorize.net:443/anetseal/seal.js" ></script> </div>
```

I'm trying to put it below this tag

```
<a href="http://www.geriatricadvisorycouncil.com/" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/gac-header-logo2.png" alt="Geriatric Advisory Council " /></a>
```

but it didn't show anything.

Comment: What is issue please provide url

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code.

```
<a href="http://www.geriatricadvisorycouncil.com/" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory().'/images/gac-header-logo2.png';?> alt="Geriatric Advisory Council " /></a>
```

Make sure you that you put the image in images folder of your current active theme directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://www.geriatricadvisorycouncil.com/" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/gac-header-logo2.png" alt="Geriatric Advisory Council " /></a>
```

Inspect your code with `F12, or Ctrl+Shift+I` and check the error on `console tab`. It may be possible that the path of your logo is not found, that's why your logo is not apearing.

You can also check it by echo the complete path(url) of the image by this you can check and correct the error.